# Topology question on homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be the subspace $(-\infty, 4) \cup [5, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as

$$
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x+1, &\text{for } x < 4
    \\
    x, &\text{for } x \geq 5.
  \end{cases}
$$

How do I show that $f$ is surjective? Is $f$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: f is not surjective because its codomain is  R.

Comment: You wrote $(-\infty,4)\cup(5,\infty)$; did you mean $(-\infty,4)\cup\color{red}[5,\infty)$

Comment: Did you make a picture of the graph of $f$ ?

Comment: It cannot be a homeomorphism as its domain is not connected and its codomain is connected, and connectedness is unvariant under homeomorphism. You can show that its inverse function is not continuous at $5$.